# Need to configure 2008 server with 2 NICs on different subnets

Tags: windows-server-2008, nic

I am working on an application that requires a 2008 server to have 2 NICs for security purposes.

NIC 1 will be connected to the customer's enterprise network with a static IP and is routable. It needs to be able to communicate with other applications on the Enterprise network (e.g. 10.56.71.26). That system is currently working and properly presenting to the applications.

I will be using NIC 2 to communicate with a RS232-->TCP/IP converter box. Networking wise, we can assume that the converter box is a workstation (it's only purpose is to tunnel RS232 data to the server where a Windows driver will emulate a receiving serial port. Also the converter box only needs to communicate with the server. Additionally the converter box doesn't need to communicate with the rest of the enterprise network. The converter is on a private network with a static of 192.168.1.2 (255.255.255.0). Do I need to do anything else other than assign an IP to NIC 2 of 192.168.1.1 (255.255.255.0)?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Simon - simply configure the 192.168.1.1 address and mask on NIC 2, and leave DNS and gateway blank. One additional step as a best practice is to set the primary (NIC1) at the top of the binding order to make sure your normal traffic always goes out of that interface. If you haven't done that before, see:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732472(v=WS.10).aspx

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Define the relevant IP and subnet mask on both NICs.  As it sounds like you'll need to talk to other stuff of NIC1, define the first-hop (default) gateway for NIC1 too.  Leave this blank for NIC2.

As you're only talking to one device on NIC2, and it falls within the address range of the network 192.168.1.0/24, you don't need any static routes.

So, yes, you're fine.